# Return string from unmanaged dll to C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, stringbuilder

I'm sorry to ask this here since I'm sure it must be answered "out there", but I've been stuck on this for several months now, and none of the solutions I've found have worked for me.

I have the following VB code that works:

```
Declare Function DeviceSendRead Lib "unmanaged.dll" (ByVal sCommand As String, ByVal sReply As String, ByVal sError As String, ByVal Timeout As Double) As Integer

Dim err As Integer
Dim outstr As String
Dim readstr As String
Dim errstr As String

outstr = txtSend.Text
readstr = Space(4000)
errstr = Space(100)

Timeout = 10

err = DeviceSendRead(outstr, readstr, errstr, Timeout)
```

and I am trying to implement it in a C# project. The best equivalent I have been able to find is:

```
    [DllImport("unmanaged.dll")] public static extern int DeviceSendRead(String outstr, StringBuilder readstr, StringBuilder errstr, double Timeout);

    int err;
    StringBuilder readstr = new StringBuilder(4000);
    StringBuilder errstr = new StringBuilder(100);

    err = DeviceSendRead(txtSend.Text, readstr, errstr, 10);
```

However, when I run this, the application freezes and I must force quit it. By experimenting with ref and out, I have occasionally managed to make it crash rather than freeze, but the only "progress" I have achieved is to replace the dll function call with:

```
    DeviceSendRead(txtSend.Text, null, null, 10);
```

This prevents the crash, but of course does nothing (that I can detect). I'm therefore assuming that it's the manner of passing the two return string parameters that is causing the problem. If anyone can suggest what I might be doing wrong, I'd be very happy to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you build unmanaged.dll yourself or is this some third party library that you don't have to source code to?

Comment: You may need to marshal the parameters. Using the MarshalAs attribute.

Comment: As yousuggest, this is a third party library without source code or documentation. I wouldn't be attempting to make it work if it weren't for the fact that the VB code works, and so I thought it should be possible from C# too.

Comment: Your calling convention in C# could be wrong. I think DllImport defaults to StdCall (WinApi). If the dll uses a standard C export, it's probably Cdecl.

Comment: StringBuilder is definitely the way to go for `out` strings, but the only difference in marshalling behaviour that I know of between VB and C# is that VB defaults to `ExactSpelling` and C# doesn't. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f.aspx) seems to suggest their behaviour should be identical, but maybe try explicitly specifying the `CharSet` in your `DllImport`.

Comment: Is it also possible that the function is trying to _read_ those parameters, and choking on the uninitialised characters it finds? It seems unlikely, given how they're named, but if you try `StringBuilder readstr = new StringBuilder(new string(' ', 1000));` (and similarly for the errstr) rather than `new StringBuilder(1000)`, then you'll be passing the same values _in_ that the VB version does

Comment: Thanks for these helpful suggestions. I have implemented the last one and also added the attributes 'CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl'. Unfortunately, the behaviour remains unchanged. I appreciate your attempts to assist.

Comment: If you do not have any code for the native DLL and you do not know anything about the specification of the function you are calling you are in big trouble. Replace this part of your code with something that you know and understand. Guessing doesn't work.

Comment: The only thing different between the VB6 code and the pinvoke is that the VB6 code returns a 16 bit int and so you shuold use `short` in your C# pinvoke. But since it comes back in EAX that's not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Why would `CallingConvention.Cdecl` be appropriate? The VB6 code means `stdcall`. From what I can see your problem lies elsewhere. Perhaps you are not initialising the library correctly. There's something else that is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm tending to agree with you at this stage. I may have to abandon it (or stick to VB). Other functions in the library (that don't return strings) work fine. Thanks to everyone for attempting to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reached an answer, which I will record here for completeness, with grateful thanks to all those who pointed me in the right direction.

According to [this post](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/613886-dll-import-method) elsewhere, the use of .NET Reflector on similar VB code suggests the need to use the `string` type in place of my `StringBuilder`, as suggested here by Alex Mendez, JamieSee and Austin Salonen, together with explicit marshaling, as suggested by Nanhydrin, but utilising the unmanaged type `VBByRefStr` rather than `AnsiBStr`. The final key to the puzzle is that the string parameter then needs to be passed by reference using the `ref` keyword.

I can confirm that this works, and that my final working C# code is therefore:

```
    [DllImport("unmanaged.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern short DeviceSendRead(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string sCommand,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string sReply,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)] ref string sError,
        double Timeout);

            short err;
            string outstr = txtSend.Text;
            string readstr = new string(' ', 4000);
            string errstr = new string(' ', 100);

            err = DeviceSendRead(ref outstr, ref readstr, ref errstr, 10);
```

I hope this is useful to others facing a similar issue.

Comment: For the future, search for answers to questions about the Windows function GetWindowText; it is similar and all the answers I find that work use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an equivalent:

```
string readstr = new string(' ', 4000);
string errstr = new string(' ', 1000);
```

Comment: Why are you using `string.Join`? Wouldn't `new String(' ', 4000)` be faster?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[DllImport("unmanaged.dll")]
public static extern int DeviceSendRead(string outString, string readString, string errorString, double timeout);


int err;
string outstr;
string readstr;
string errstr =
outstr = txtSend.Text;
readstr = new string(' ', 4000);
errstr = new string(' ', 100);
double timeout = 10;
err = DeviceSendRead(outstr, readstr, errstr, timeout);
```

Comment: Thanks for this and other similar suggestions. I have tried this code, but the result is the same: the application freezes. I was able to get it to generate an exception in the debugger, which says: "FatalExecutionEngineError was detected. Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x6ab49795, on thread 0x1248. The error code is 0x80131506. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack."

Comment: Perhaps if we had the code for the unmanaged.dll or the dll itself we could assist a little further. But, without that we are kind of guessing.

Comment: Yes, I have that feeling, as pointed out by David Heffernan. I don't have the code for the dll, and I don't know how to give you the dll itself. I would gladly pay cash for a working C# version of the VB project.

Comment: Can you zip the code and send it to me @ alexmendez127@gmail.com? If it is more than 5mb, split it into different emails.

Answer (score 0):

[Default Marshalling for strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx)
[Default Marshalling behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah6xy75.aspx)

You may need to be more specific in your dllimport declaration and add in some MarshalAs attributes, if you have more details on what type of strings the called function is expecting (Ansi, Unicode, null terminated, etc.) then that would help.
In fact it expecting null terminated strings could perhaps explain why it's hanging rather than erroring out.

```
[DllImport("unmanaged.dll", EntryPoint="DeviceSendRead")]  
public static extern int DeviceSendRead(string outString, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]string readString, string errorString, double timeout);
```

You might also need to explicitly state that your parameters are input, output, or both by using the parameter attributes [In, Out].

Answer (score -1):

```
[DllImport("unmanaged.dll", EntryPoint="DeviceSendRead")]
public static extern int DeviceSendRead(string outstr, string readstr, string errstr, double Timeout);
```

You cannot marshal a StringBuilder here. There are some rules to follow for marshalling StringBuilder (see [CLR Inside Out: Marshaling between Managed and Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx)):

> StringBuilder and Marshaling
>
> The CLR marshaler has built-in knowledge of the StringBuilder type and
>   treats it differently from other types. By default, StringBuilder is
>   passed as [InAttribute, OutAttribute]. StringBuilder is special
>   because it has a Capacity property that can determine the size of the
>   required buffer at run time, and it can be changed dynamically.
>   Therefore, during the marshaling process, the CLR can pin
>   StringBuilder, directly pass the address of internal buffer used in
>   StringBuilder, and allow the contents of this buffer to be changed by
>   native code in place.
>
> To take full advantage of StringBuilder, you'll need to follow all of
>   these rules:
>
> 1.Don't pass StringBuilder by reference (using out or ref). Otherwise, the CLR will expect the signature of this argument to be wchar_t **
>   instead of wchar_t *, and it won't be able to pin StringBuilder's
>   internal buffer. Performance will be significantly degraded.
>
> 2.Use StringBuilder when the unmanaged code is using Unicode. Otherwise, the CLR will have to make a copy of the string and convert
>   it between Unicode and ANSI, thus degrading performance. Usually you
>   should marshal StringBuilder as LPARRAY of Unicode characters or as
>   LPWSTR.
>
> 3.Always specify the capacity of StringBuilder in advance and make sure the capacity is big enough to hold the buffer. The best practice
>   on the unmanaged code side is to accept the size of the string buffer
>   as an argument to avoid buffer overruns. In COM, you can also use
>   size_is in IDL to specify the size.

Rule 3 doesn't seem like it is satisied here.

Comment: Thank you. I had browsed this link before -- it was where I got the StringBuilder approach (Buffers Sample). However, I will take a second look. If you think any one of the approaches in particular is appropriate here, I'd be grateful for a further pointer.

Comment: @user1203108 Can you provide the actual function signature for the unmanaged code?

Comment: Thanks for the expanded comment JamieSee. I have no documentation for the unmanaged dll beyond the example VB code shown in my original post, which works. I thought the capacity of the StringBuilder was specified through its constructor as `StringBuilder readstr = new StringBuilder(4000);` but I may have misunderstood what is intended here. I have also been trying your suggested code using `string`s, with the results outlined in the other comments.

Comment: @user1203108 Interestingly enough I stumbled across something that says that when you use VB.NET, "You apply this attribute directly to C# and C++ method definitions; however, the Visual Basic compiler emits this attribute when you use the Declare statement." I wonder if you could use Declare in VB.NET and then use a disassembler and end up getting the DllImport you need that way?